# Usar Py2Exe con PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Tengo la intención de transcribir un programa C++ que utiliza Qt, a Python, ya que llegó la hora de actualizarlo desde la vieja versión 3 de Qt. Sin embargo, al intentar recompilar usando las nuevas Qt5, me encuetro con que la mitad del código debe ser reescrito de nuevo.
Entonces se me ocurrió reescribirlo desde cero en Python, aprovechando que también es posible usar Qt con él. El tema es que Python no sólo es famoso por su facilidad de aprendizaje y expresividad, sinó también por su lentitud de ejecución, y es por eso quisiera acelerarlo al máximo mediante la compilación a ejecutable nativo. Tengo entendido que Py2Exe lo hace muy bien, pero no sé si admite librerías de terceros, particularmente pyQt5.
¿Alguien sabe si es posible combinar Py2Exe con Qt para lograr programas claros, consisos y rápidos?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrias modificar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo que ya llevas

Comment: ¿El código? No tengo problemas de código. Solo quisiera saber si es posible combinar pyQt5 con Py2Exe.

Comment: no solo la parte donde queres combinar Py2Exe con Qt

Comment: Mi idea es, de ser posible, reescribir completamente el programa en python + Qt5, pero solamente si es posible compilarlo completamente a ejecutable nativo (no alguna sección si y otra no), de modo de conseguir un .exe único junto con las dll de Qt que hagan falta. El programa ademas de usar Qt para la interface de usuario, también lo usa para trabajar con mysql. Por eso quisiera saber si Py2exe puede crear ejecutables a partir de Python3 + Pyqt5. Si hay alguna limitación entre lo que puede o no compilar, creo que se me complicaría el trabajo en vez de simplificarlo.